# Gif loading ao pesquisar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocompletar

Olá

Estou implementando [esse](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/funcao-autocompletar-com-jquery-php-e-banco-de-dados) autocompletar

E gostaria de que enquanto o sistema pesquisa os itens, ele mostrar um gif de carregando no canto do input.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

A linha abaixo em css funciona, mas não sei onde inserir:

```
.ac_loading {
    background: white url('indicator.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
```

Esse [tutorial](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/funcao-autocompletar-com-jquery-php-e-banco-de-dados) aparece, só que o código dele é antigo e dá conflito em algumas funções, que não funcionam mas tem o que eu gostaria de fazer:

```
$.Autocompleter.defaults = {
    inputClass: "ac_input",
    resultsClass: "ac_results",
    loadingClass: "ac_loading",
```

Por exemplo, esse último código dá o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined
```

É isso!

Comment: Não sei como fazer corretamente, mas assim, você pode usar o 'search' para iniciar o loading, e o 'select' para finalizar o loading. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127917/how-do-i-add-an-event-when-jquery-autocomplete-results-are-complete

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626591/lazy-initialization-of-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: Bom está dando certo, só falta eu conseguir ao perder o foco também sumir o loading, mas sua sua ideia está dando certo

Comment: Pronto, por favor adicione como resposta que deu certo, para então eu marcar como resolvido

Comment: Que bom que ajudou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os métodos `search` para iniciar o seu loading, e o `select` para finalizar ele do autocomplete.

```
$("#searchFirstTransactionStateInfo_searchPartnerId").autocomplete({
   search: function( event, ui ) {
        iniciaLoading();
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        finalizaLoading();   
    }
});
```

Links úteis:

Como inializar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626591/lazy-initialization-of-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Como finalizar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127917/how-do-i-add-an-event-when-jquery-autocomplete-results-are-complete

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Excelente. Deu certo